# WordPress Comment posting problem

Tags: posts, comments

I am getting trouble with WordPress comment posting.
As per my WP setting there is no approval needed to display the comments under blog after posting.
Most of the comments posted display immediately. But some of them do not display and need aproval from the admin / Author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check all of the following options under `Dashboard -> Settings -> Discussion`:

**Before a comment appears**

- Before a comment appears  An administrator must always approve the comment
- Comment author must have a previously approved comment

**Comment Moderation**

- Hold a comment in the queue if it contains *_* or more links. (A common characteristic of comment spam is a large number of hyperlinks.)
- When a comment contains any of these words in its content, name, URL, e-mail, or IP, it will be held in the moderation queue. One word or IP per line. It will match inside words, so “press” will match “WordPress”.

Also: do you have any comment-moderation or spam-prevention Plugins active?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have checked all the settings and I think it will be good for future comments posting.
But how to change the status of all older unproved comments to approve for all blogs posted?

Comment: If comments are already in moderation, you will simply have to approve them. You can bulk-approve them from the `Dashboard -> Comments` screen, by checking the checkbox for all of them, then selecting "Approve" in the "Bulk Actions" dropdown, and then clicking "Apply".

Comment: Thanks. I have seen the bulk approve option. 
I have now allowed any and everyone to post a comment without moderation
But wouldn't that allow all the  previous posts awaiting moderation to become automatically approved?

Comment: No; changing comment settings does not alter the status of existing comments.